# Can I read block.coinbase of the current block?

Tags: solidity

I'm looking into some Solidity functions and block.coinbase caught my attention. It returns the address of a block's miner. Can it be read for the current block or just for previous blocks like blockhash?

Answer (score 1):

When your transaction gets included in a block, it's done by a miner. So the `block.coinbase` will point to that miner.

Multiple miners may include the transaction in their block around the same time, and in their block the `block.coinbase` is different. But eventually the blockchain reaches a consensus and agrees which block to keep and ditch the others. So, as long as you are in the winning chain (not a problem usually), you can trust the `block.coinbase`.

I don't see any functionality to use it to see the miners of previous blocks, like in `blockhash`.

Comment: Ok, since nobody knows which miner will be on the winning chain, if I use block.coinbase as seed for a pseudorandom number generation, combined with the sender address, the only way to manipulate it would be if the miner and the sender would collude, is that correct?

Comment: That's an interesting proposition. But, sorry, I can't think that far currently. Feel free to post a new question about it, and do let me know, thanks

Comment: When a miner initiates the PoW processing, is the block.coinbase value or a related value (miner address or original pk) included in the PoW puzzle input?